# Is it possible to compile a dll with subset of classes from the class library project?

Tags: c#, dll

Say we have a class library project containing 10 classes. Now I want to create a dll which should contatin only 6 classes out of those 10. How we can achieve this?

Comment: Note that if you just want to hide the 4 classes to the others libraries, you can use the `internal` modifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use compiler directives.  E.g.

```
#define ClassA
#if ClassA
class A
{
}
#endif

#undef ClassB
#if ClassB
class B
{
}
#endif
```

Class A would be included and Class B would not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you follow the common practice of putting one class in one source code file: select the classes you don't want to include in Solution Explorer and set their Build Action property to None.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a second project file in a nearby folder and point it at the six source files containing the classes you want. This way you end up with two binaries with different names and version numbers, which will make life MUCH less confusing later on.

Otherwise you risk someone putting the wrong binary down, and either shipping four classes you want to keep hidden, or failing to ship four classes that are acutally needed.

Come to think of it, you don't mention whether there's any interaction between the six you want and the four you don't want. Assuming there isn't, just pull the six out into a separate project and have two "class library" binaries, one with six and one with four. That way there's no duplication of functionality or possible confusion about which binaries contain which classes.

Comment: Most of the classes are unrelated, and main purpose behind doing this is, I don't want to ship unrelated utility classes to client side.

Comment: Then I'd definitely say split them into separate binaries and spare yourself a lot of pain later on when folks get confused about which class is supposed to come from which binary or which binary they need to ship to get which combination of classes.

Comment: Ok, Let me tell you the scene. Classes are less ( 7-8 ), All are utility classes, so i have put them into a dll called utils. Now for a project 2-3 classes are not required. I don't want to ship these 2-3 classes to clients who don't require them. What should be the best strategy?

Comment: Useless but short answer: it depends!
If you've got lots of apps that are already shipped against this common class library, and intend shipping new versions of those apps, then actually shipping the 2-3 unnecessary classes is probably the lesser evil.
If this is the first time utils.dll has shipped, then I'd split it now and put the six you want to ship into one binary with a more meaningful name than "utils" and put the other four into a second binary with a different meaningful name.

Answer (score 0):

**`Exclude`** them from project and **`build`**. Pick the **`dll`** from **`Debug`** or **`Release`** folder.

Answer (score 0):

Place the unnecessary classes inside a **#ifdef EXTRA ... #endif** bracket and you can then define EXTRA or not during compilation to get those additional classes.